# Rails partial either not creating variables local to partial or errors with a strange error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

So I have the following HTML in my main template:

```
<% unless @upfront_costs.blank? %>
  <%= render partial: 'upfront_costs', object: @upfront_costs do %>
    There are also several upfront Costs that need to be made, these will be required to be paid for after checkout.
    The upfront costs are as follows:
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and the following partials:
_upfront_costs.html.erb:

```
<p>
  <%= yield %>
</p>
<ul>
  <%= render partial: 'upfront_cost', collection: upfront_costs %>
</ul>
```

_upront_cost.html.erb:

```
<li>
  <p>
    <%= upfront_cost[:service_title] %> - <%= upfront_cost[:reason] %> : <%= upfront_cost[:amount].currency.symbol %><%= upfront_cost[:amount] %>
  </p>
</li>
```

With the `partial:` I get this error `'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.`

Without the `partial:` I get this error `'undefined local variable or method 'upfront_costs' for #<#<Class:0x00007fb772a767b0>:0x00007fb777408478>
Did you mean?  @upfront_costs`

`@upfront_costs` is an array that has hash objects in it.

What is going on and how do I fix it?

Comment: Looks like you are missing `<% end %>` in your first snippet.

Comment: ah, no it's there, I just hadn't noticed I hadn't included it in the end of the snippet, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is here:

```
<%= render partial: 'upfront_costs', object: @upfront_costs do %>
```

you variable is called `object` instead of `upfront_costs`. you need something like this:

```
<%= render partial: 'upfront_costs', upfront_costs: @upfront_costs do %>
```

EDIT: Rails will create variables with the keys you pass into the partial... you could do either what I've suggested or use `object` inside `_upfront_costs.html.erb`:

```
  <%= render partial: 'upfront_cost', collection: object %>
```

Comment: why isn't working when passing in it using the `object:` option?, also I'm getting `undefined method 'upfront_cost'` for the `upfront_cost` partial despiting parsing in the object as a collection.

Comment: isn't working cos rails will create variables with the keys you pass into the partial... you could do either what I've suggested or use `object` inside `_upfront_costs.html.erb`

Comment: Did they change this? Becuase according to the docs, thats what you do, pass in an `object:` and a variable called the same as the partial will be created that will reference the object passed in to the `object` option, I'm also getting the same issue with passing in an object to the `collection` option. Here are the docs in question: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Comment: not sure, maybe it's because `@upfront_costs` isn't an `ActiveRecord` object?

Answer (score 0):

Replace partial with layout as follows

```
<% unless @upfront_costs.blank? %>
  <%= render layout: 'upfront_costs', object: @upfront_costs do %>
   There are also several upfront Costs that need to be made, these will 
   be required to be paid for after checkout.
   The upfront costs are as follows:
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```